# Why is object coming up as undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get some location coordinates in this function

```
getLocation(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?",
        dataType:'json',
        success:function (data) {
            this.setState({
                coordinates:data
            },function () {
                console.log(this.state);
            })
        }.bind(this),
        error:function (xhr,status,err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
}
```

I call it in the componentWillMount() stage and try to populate this structure.

```
this.state = {
    restaurantsByLocations:{},
    coordinates:{}
}
```

However, when I try to pass it to

```
getRestaurantsByLocation(lat,longi){
/**Some code here **/

}
```

It doesn't get passed. On Doing console.log(), my object is populated. However on doing  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.coordinates)), it shows that the object is indeed empty.

This is my componentWillMount()

```
componentWillMount(){

this.getLocation();
this.getRestaurantsByLocation(this.state.coordinates.latitude,this.state.coordinates.longitude)


}
```

Comment: This is an async call, so it takes time. When you do console.log, it keeps the reference so when it changes, you see it. When you do stringify, you keep the value at this given time, and your state isnt set yet. EDIT : you should always do async call on ComponentDidMount, so your view update when you update your state : https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Could you also add your debugging `console.log`s to the question, including their result?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your solutions! The issue was indeed the async call, I will make sure to educated myself more. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is call your `getRestaurantsByLocation` function in your `setState` callback. That way, you make sure to have the necessary information when the function is called, unlike your method. Would look like this:

```
getLocation(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?",
        dataType:'json',
        success:function (data) {
            this.setState({
                coordinates:data
            },function () {
                this.getRestaurantsByLocation(data.latitude,data.longitude)
            })
        }.bind(this),
        error:function (xhr,status,err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected and was pretty easy to implement! Sloppy from my side.

Answer (score 1):

`getLocation` is asynchronous, JavaScript won't wait for it to finish before it moves on to the `getRestaurantsByLocation` call.

You could pass `getRestaurantsByLocation` as a callback to fire once it's completed though, something like this...

```
function getLocation(onLocationAvailable) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/my/endpoint/',
        success: function(data) {
            onLocationAvailable(data.longitude, data.latitude);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Then call `getLocation` like this...

```
getLocation(getRestaurantsByLocation);
```

This will mean that `getRestaurantsByLocation` is only called once the data has come back from the server. You could, of course, still store the lat and long in state if you want to and then call the callback but I think it's clearer to pass through the data it needs explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong, but when you are using this.state in your ajax function, does 'this' is your page or the ajax call ?

in your getLocation() function, i would create a var `var _this = this;`

Then use it as a reference for your page :

```
_this.setState({
   coordinates:data
},function () {
   console.log(_this.state);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` within the AJAX call is not referencing your component because of scoping. Try the following:

```
getLocation(){
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url:"//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?",
        dataType:'json',
        success:function (data) {
            that.setState({
                coordinates:data
            },function () {
                console.log(this.state);
            })
        }.bind(this),
        error:function (xhr,status,err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
}
```

By doing so, you have effectively created a closure of the component context that the `success` callback within the AJAX can reference. So now you should be able to `setState` without a problem.

One last thing, with React you may also need to bind the context depending on which version you are using. I typically do it in my constructor, for example:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.getLocation = this.getLocation.bind(this);
  this.state = {coordinates: xyz};
}
```

Comment: But he told us his `console.log(this.state)` returned the expected result. Meaning this isn't the issue here? Or am I missing something